# Select element based on cousin value

Tags: xpath

Lets say I have this html (ignore tags names):

```
<div>
    <card>
        <h2>1</h2>
    </card>
    <footer>
        <p>text 1</p>
    </footer>
</div>

<div>
     <card>
        <h2>2</h2>
    </card>
    <footer>
        <p>text 2</p>
    </footer>
</div>

<div>
    <card>
        <h2>3</h2>
    </card>
    <footer>
       <p>text 2</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

and I want to select p tag that have an h2 value of 2 (I will select p with text 2)

if I use this expression `//h2[text()="2"]/../following::footer/p` I will get 2 p tags.

How do I select only the p tag with cousin `h2` value of `2` ?

EDIT: Robbie Averill answer was the first to work, but you should check other answers they are very good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate from the `h2` matched up to the `div` that contains the element you want, then target `footer/p` elements from there:

```
//h2[text()="2"]/../../footer/p
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below XPath to select required element:

```
//card[h2="2"]/following-sibling::footer/p
```

Comment: Specifying conditions in the heritage like this is cleaner than `../..` tree traversals. (+1)

Comment: If `card` - `footer` ordering is insignificant, we can [simplify even more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52741658/290085).

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//div[card/h2="2"]/footer/p
```

will select `footer/p` cousins of `card/h2` elements with string values of `2`.